# Android Layout Meassurement Values Only Even Numbers?

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering if there is a conscious intention of using even numbers for measurement units when building Android layouts. For example in the [Android desgin guidelines](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html) there are always multiple of 2 being used as I could see, at least I don't remember Google ever using 3, 5 or so for padding/margin, is there an official reference talking about this somewhere so I could strongly argument that using uneven numbers is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is just a coincidence that material design has even numbers for their `dp` measurements. As you can see here it is not a rule, just a coincidence. [Typography](https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html) has some examples of *odd* measurements:

```
Subheading

English: Regular 16sp (device), 15sp (desktop)
Dense: Regular 17sp (device), 16sp (desktop)
Tall: Regular 17sp (device), 16sp (desktop)
```

Generally, sizes are increased exponentially rather than linearly. Or atleast differences between subsequent sizes increases. *(Because human brains think logarithmically instead of linearly: [Why In Our Brains The Midpoint Of 1 And 9 Might Be 3](http://www.science20.com/news_articles/logarithm_versus_linear_thinking_why_our_brains_midpoint_1_and_9_might_be_3-94891))*

Like `2dp, 4dp, 8dp`, or `160, 240, 320, 480, 640`[(Image scaling)](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-designing-layouts-for-dp)

So if you start with a `2`, you'll get all even numbers but if you start with a `1` or `5`, you'll get odd numbers as well.

It could just as well have been `5, 10, 25, 50`.

[Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#less-variables-components) has some *odd* measurements:

```
@padding-small-vertical:         5px;
@padding-small-horizontal:       10px;

@padding-xs-vertical:            1px;
@padding-xs-horizontal:          5px;
```

But even here the exponential growth is visible.